# How to build an Android Studio project cloned from git?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I'm building a library for Android in Android Studio. In order to test and debug this library, I created a project with two modules: a library module (my code) and an app module (for testing)

Creating these was pretty easy. I just clicked `File > New... > Project` and followed the prompts. Afterwards I was able to write code, hit build, and observe the results in the app that was generated.

After a couple of months, everything was ready to deploy. I've been regularly committing my code and pushing it to a central repository, so another developer at my company cloned the repository and tried to open it in Android Studio. He was met with an entirely different view.

This is what I see:

[image]

This is what is seen if you clone the repo and open it:

[image]

When looking at the second view there's no way to build the project, there are no build configurations, no variants, and none of the gradle scripts seem to run.

If instead of cloning I just `cp -r` my entire project directory and open ***that*** in Android Studio, it opens perfectly. So the issue seems to lie with something in my `.gitignore` hiding an important configuration file necessary to build the project.

The `.gitignore` was generated for my automatically by Android Studio. It looks like this:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/caches
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/navEditor.xml
/.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
```

Everything there ***should*** be files generated by the build tools or local workspace configuration files, not project-level files necessary to compile. But I'm not very familiar with Android, its build steps, or the 800,000 things Android Studio is implicitly and secretly doing behind my back. Just opening the project in Android Studio causes 12 or so files to get modified on disk, so I know that it's doing a ***lot*** of things behind my back.

I can share any details about my configuration or project setup as necessary. I've spent a few hours on this already and can't figure out for the life of me how to get this project to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's probably not the ***proper*** solution (after all, Android Studio created the `.gitignore` for me), I found that removing `/.idea/modules.xml` from the `.gitignore` and checking in this file fixed all of my issues. Suddenly when I launched Android Studio it detected everything, some Gradle scripts ran, and I was able to build my project.